# Eclipse crash in Ubuntu Mate 15.04

Tags: 15.04, java, eclipse, mate

I'm currently on Ubuntu Mate 15.04 and have installed Eclipse Mars directly from the official website.

My Eclipse version:
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Build id: 20150924-1200

Unfortunately, when I'm trying to use it, after clicking on some button (for example doing a right click on the C/C++ button in the top right corner) get me to a crash.

I then get a crash report (.log) in my /home file with written :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9f09801d41, pid=14037, tid=140321501198080
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_66-b17) (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.66-b17 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgdk-3.so.0+0x3dd41]  gdk_window_ensure_native+0x31
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

There are actually about 1500 lines in those log files.
From the crash report, the problem comes from Java. I have installed Java 7 and Java 8. Tried to uninstall one to have only one at a time, still crash.

From what I have read, there may be some bugs because of GTK or something like that but I still don't know what to do to fix it.
Do you have any idea ?

Thanks forward :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it gives you a PID, or process ID, so go into a task manager to check which specific process is causing the error. Assuming it's a problem with the runtime, the best advice for you would be to completely uninstall all java versions. As of right now, the log isn't specific enough.
**Edit**: Perhaps your version of libgdk is outdated, and could be upgraded via

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Otherwise, I'd suggest removing libgdk and installing the latest version, which most likely will not cause the crash.

Comment: I actually already tried to uninstall all java versions, and install them again but got again and again the same crashes.

Comment: Okay, well it seems that libgdk is what's causing the crashes, probably because some of the java natives libraries are having compatibility issues

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The upgrade did not solve the issue.
How do I remove libgdk and install the last version ?

Comment: sudo apt-get remove libgdk -That removes it, and you'd do sudo apt-get install libgdk to reinstall the latest version.

Comment: It is telling me that he doesnt find the paquage. When I try to uninstall it and even when I try to install it...